# How do I make it skip if It cant find the button in Imacro

Tags: imacros

Hey I'm trying to make a script for a website but I need help

This is the button:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Enter<SP>Raffle
```

this is the error I get:

> RuntimeError: element BUTTON specified by TXT:EnterRaffle was not found, line 7 (Error code: -921)

How do I make it skip if it can't find the button ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ERRORIGNORE](http://wiki.imacros.net/!ERRORIGNORE) tag, as the example below:

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:EnterRaffle
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
```

Hope it helps.